# Usage of vlimit to limit resource for a process in Linux

Tags: linux, operating-system, linux-kernel

Found mention of vlimit to specify resource usage limit for a process.

Function: int vlimit (int resource, int limit)

vlimit sets the current limit for a resource for a process.

Is it an obsolete method now ? How different is it from prlimit ?

Answer (score 2):

`vlimit()` is ancient. POSIX.1-2001 specifies [`getrlimit()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html) and [`setrlimit()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) you should use instead.

[`prlimit()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/prlimit.2.html) is a Linux-specifc GNU extension, which performs the same tasks for an arbitrary process (if you have the necessary privileges); instead for setting or requesting the limits for the current process, you specify the process ID of the process whose limits you wish to query/set. (To query, set the third parameter to `NULL`. To only set, set the fourth parameter to `NULL`. If neither is NULL, then the current limits are queried first, then the new limits set.)